# how can i fetch database records between two dates in drupal

Tags: drupal-8

I need to fetch the table records from start_date to end_date ,i tried some queries but its showing all records

```
    class uniview8PastpaymentController extends ControllerBase {

public static function load($entry = array()) {
  $maxDate = \Drupal::request()->query->get('set_start_date');
  drupal_set_message(t("$maxDate"));
  $minDate = \Drupal::request()->query->get('set_end_date');
  drupal_set_message(t("$minDate"));  
    $select = db_select('pastpayments', 'example');
    $select->fields('example');

    // Add each field and value as a condition to this query.
    foreach ($entry as $field => $value) {
      $query->condition('paiddate', array($maxDate, $minDate), 'BETWEEN');
    }
    // Return the result in object format.
    return $select->execute()->fetchAll();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
   $start_time = '1493029282.696';
    $end_time = '1493029283.304';
    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('cache_data', 'nfd');
    $query->fields('nfd', ['cid', 'data', 'expire']);
    $query->condition('created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN');
    $result = $query->execute();
```